# I can't ridirect to stripe checkout from WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I have an e-commerce website made using WordPress and WooCommerce and for the payment gateway, I am working with stripe. I tried a lot of plugins like [WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/) when I click on the payment buttons it takes me to the WooCommerce checkout page and the payment will be there and WooCommerce will take care of everything but I want to redirect to the stripe checkout page. I found this plugin [Stripe Payment Plugin for WooCommerce](https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration/)  .

this plugin will allow me to redirect to stripe checkout but unfortunately I guess it has a bug in the code I get this error :

> You cannot use `line_items.amount`, `line_items.currency`,
> `line_items.name`, `line_items.description`, or `line_items.images` in
> this API version. Please use `line_items.price` or
> `line_items.price_data`.

I tried to fix it by myself but I couldn't this is parts of its PHP file

```
 $session_data['line_items'] = array(
                    [
                        'name'     => esc_html( __( 'Total', 'payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration' ) ),
                        'amount'   => $total,
                        'currency' => strtolower(get_woocommerce_currency()),
                        'quantity' => 1,
                        'images'   => array($images),
                    ]
                );

if (empty($customer_id)) { 

            $customer = $this->create_stripe_customer( $order, $user);

            $customer_id = $customer->id;
            //saved stripe customer for charging  cards later
            update_user_meta($logged_in_userid, "_stripe_ch_customer_id", $customer_id);
        }
        $session_data['customer'] = $customer_id;
        
        $session_data['payment_intent_data']['setup_future_usage'] = 'off_session';

        $session_data['locale'] = $this->stripe_checkout_page_locale;
        $session_data = apply_filters('wt_stripe_alter_checkout_request_params', $session_data, $order);
        $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create($session_data);
        
        return  array(
            'result'   => 'success',
            'redirect' => $this->get_payment_session_checkout_url( $session->id, $order ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be related to recent change to the new [API version](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#api-versions) 2022-08-01.

These parameters have been moved into the `line_items.price_data` object.  In order to pass in the data in the new shape that is required you will need to pass something like the following:

```php
$session_data['line_items'] = array(['price_data' => 
                    [
                        'name'     => esc_html( __( 'Total', 'payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration' ) ),
                        'amount'   => $total,
                        'currency' => strtolower(get_woocommerce_currency()),
                        'quantity' => 1,
                        'images'   => array($images),
                    ]
                ]);
```

You can review the [updated API reference doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) for more information

Comment: thank you this helped me solve the problem. I just edit it like this  `$session_data['line_items'] = array(
     ['price_data' => 
      [
                        'unit_amount'   => $total,
                        'currency' => strtolower(get_woocommerce_currency()),
      'product_data' => [
                        'name'     => esc_html( __( 'Total', 'payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration' ) ),

      ],
                    ],    'quantity' => 1,

                ]);`

Comment: Hello @Dev & RyanM - which file did you make these changes? I am unable to located the file with the above code.

Comment: @Aquaholic you can find it like this : `wp-content / plugins / payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration / includes / class-stripe-checkout.php`